# Acessar WS com file_get_content utilizando lista de proxy

Tags: php

Eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
function pegarWS($numero){

    $PEGAR_WS = 'http://ws.com.br';
    $URL = $PEGAR_WS.$numero;
    $arrayReturn = json_decode( @file_get_contents($URL), true );
```

Eu queria acessar a URL através de vários proxy

Achei algo do tipo:

```
$proxies = array( '192.168.0.2:3128', '192.168.8.2:3128', '192.168.10.2:80' );

// Pick a random proxy:
$proxy_to_use = $proxies[ rand( 0, count( $proxies ) -1) ];

$aContext = array(
  'http' => array(
    'proxy' => 'tcp://' . $proxy_to_use,
    'request_fulluri' => true,
  ),
);
```

Consegui resolver o problema com a resposta do Guilherme.

Ficou assim o código:

```
function pegarWS($numero){

    $PEGAR_WS = 'http://ws.com.br';
    $URL = $PEGAR_WS.$numero;

$proxies = file('pasta/secreta/inacessivel/via/http/proxies.txt');

//Limpa espaços em branco
$proxies = array_map(function ($proxy) {
    return trim($proxy);
}, $proxies);

// pegar random proxy
$proxy_to_use = $proxies[ rand( 0, count( $proxies ) -1 ];

$aContext = array(
  'http' => array(
    'proxy' => $proxy_to_use,
    'request_fulluri' => true,
  ),
);

$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

 $arrayReturn = json_decode( @file_get_contents($URL, false, $cxContext), true);
```

Com opção de buscar em um .txt.

Agora estou parado em outro ponto.

```
    $proxy_to_use = $proxies[ rand( 0, count( $proxies ) -1) ];
```

É possível que ele leia o arquivo txt do primeiro ao último e depois faça o processo novamente? sem que seja de forma random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porque isto esta errado:

```
 $arrayReturn = json_decode( @file_get_contents($URL), true, $cxContext );
```

O `$cxContext` tem que ir no `file_get_contents`, assim:

```
 $arrayReturn = json_decode( @file_get_contents($URL, false, $cxContext), true);
```

Como o AP pediu, pode também deixar os IPs em um `proxies.txt` e lista-los assim (com quebra de linhas):

```
192.168.0.2:3128
192.168.8.2:3128
192.168.10.2:80
```

E então leria assim:

```
$proxies = file('pasta/secreta/inacessivel/via/http/proxies.txt');

//Limpa espaços em branco
$proxies = array_map(function ($proxy) {
    return trim($proxy);
}, $proxies);

// pegar random proxy
$proxy_to_use = $proxies[ rand( 0, count( $proxies ) -1 ];
```

Comment: Salvou @Guilherme~ ! Uma outra dúvida, é possível chamar em um arquivo.txt com os proxy? Como ficaria?

Comment: @Marcelo .txt local, no mesmo servidor? Chamar seria o mesmo q ler o arquivo?

Comment: sim. O arquivo ficaria no servidor e para não listar todos os números de proxy no código eu queria ler eles por um txt (para ficar fácil a edição)

Comment: @Marcelo ah entendi, vc quer deixar os IPs de proxy em um .txt, vou colocar um exemplo na resposta

Comment: @Marcelo editei a resposta, veja se é isso o que deseja

Comment: deu certo. Muito obrigado! Editei a pergunta com uma observação, se conseguir ajudar. Obrigado!